# selecting only NON NULL values in Oracle sql table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table that has 40 columns/headers and 15 rows(may vary due to the high volume records); In the records/data, many columns which have NULL values or in other words, these columns were not in a production environment, so no validation required or to list in the output.
I wanna list only the NON NULL values(Column vise) in the select table even if the entire Column is NULL.

| COLUMNS | Col_A | Col_B | Col_C | Col_D | Col_E | Col_F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ROW1 | Val_1 | Val_2 | NULL | Val_4 | Val_5 | Val_6 |
| ROW2 | Val_1 | Val_2 | NULL | Val_4 | Val_5 | NULL |

Here I want to list all the columns except "Column C" which is NULL

Comment: " I wanna list only the NON NULL values(Column vise) in the select table even if the entire Column is NULL." - That's contradictory. Could you post a simple example of source data and desired output?

Comment: COLUMNS | Col_A | Col_B | Col_C | Col_D | Col_E | Col_F | so on... ROW1 | Val_1 | Val_2 | NULL | Val_4 |Val_5| Val_6 | so on... ROW2 | Val_1 | Val_2 | NULL | Val_4 |Val_5| NULL | so on... Now I wanna list all the columns except "Column C" which is NULL – @Littlefoot

Comment: @AntonyPrincePeter Can you add that example to your post? It's hard to read in a comment.

Comment: I took the liberty of copying your example into the question.

Comment: How is the output presented ? Is this in a web application like APEX, sqlplus ? Does this have to be sql or can it be pl/sql too ? By default you determine what columns you want to select and then you limit your rows using the WHERE clause. If you want to omit columns from the resultset because they only have NULL values then you have to do some post processing.

Comment: @KoenLostrie, I have many relational tables and most of the tables have more than 15-30 columns which has both NULL and NOT NULL values. We supposed to sort out this issue to save time instead of adding each column to filter the NON NULL values in output table. Has to be SQL.

Answer (score 0):

In sql this is not possible, because that is not how a sql query works. In short this is what happens

1. You tell the database engine what columns you want to get back and what the conditions are (conditions filter rows, not columns). At this point the database does not know anything about the results. This is done using the query syntax.
2. The db engine runs the query and returns the result, row by row. The db engine does not know what is in those rows/columns.

The requirement is to skip *columns* that have no data. As explained above, that is not know at the time of running the query, but you could work around this, for example by creating a view that only has the columns with data. Bear in mind that this means that every query has to run at least once before the query itself, which could be a downside if you're talking about large datasets.

Lets create a sample table

```
CREATE TABLE tab1 (c1, c2, c3, c4) AS
(
  SELECT 1,CAST(NULL AS NUMBER), 2,4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT NULL,NULL, 1,3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 1,NULL, NULL,3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 1,NULL, 2,NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 4,NULL, 3,4 FROM DUAL
);
```

Now it's not possible to know which columns have only NULL values before we run the query, but we can run a query to *know* which columns have only NULL values using an aggregate function like `MAX`, `MIN` OR `SUM`. Lets call this QUERY1. For example:

```
SELECT MAX(c1),MAX(c2),MAX(c3),MAX(c4) FROM tab1;

   MAX(C1)    MAX(C2)    MAX(C3)    MAX(C4)
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         4                     3          4
```

Now we can convert that select so it generates another select that *that only selects the columns with not null values*. Lets call this QUERY2.

```
SELECT 
'SELECT '||
RTRIM(
NVL2(SUM(c1),'c1,','') ||
NVL2(SUM(c2),'c2,','') ||
NVL2(SUM(c3),'c3,','') ||
NVL2(SUM(c4),'c4,','')
,',')||' FROM tab1;' FROM tab1;

STMT                                                           
---------------------------------------------------------------
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW tab1_v AS SELECT c1,c3,c4 FROM tab1;
```

There you go - this statement will only return the columns that have no NULL values. Note that this is not foolproof. If a row is created or updated after you run QUERY1 but before you run QUERY2 that would alter the results of QUERY1, it could not select the correct columns.